# Component: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment error

Tags: javascript, class, components

I'm trying to make a js component that calculates the cost of storage. This includes an 8 week 50% off offer and then the price rises to 100% price for the remaining 44 weeks.

I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment." Can anyone help identify where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

```
class Company {
  constructor(companyName) {
    this._companyName = companyName;
    this._location = location;
  }

  get companyName() {
    return this._companyName;
  }

  get location() {
    return this._location;
  }
}


class EightWeeks extends Company {
  constructor(week, year, month) {
    super(companyName);
    this._week = week;
    this._year = year;
    this._month = month;
  }

  get week() {
    return this._week;
  }

  get year() {
    const yearlyCost = (this._week * 44) += (this._week * 8);
    return this.yearlyCost;
  }

  get month() {
    return this._year / 12;
  }
}

const accessHornsey = new EightWeeks ('17.77', '', '');
console.log(EightWeeks);
```

Comment: from where `location` coming in `Company` constructor ?

Comment: and you should console `accessHornsey` variable instead of `EightWeeks`

Comment: "from where location coming in Company constructor ?" - What do you mean by this?

Comment: I meant from where do you get it, it doesn't exist in constructor arguments list

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `yearlyCost` constant in `year()`. Please correct it as mentioned below:

```
get year() {
    const yearlyCost = (this._week * 44) + (this._week * 8);
    return this.yearlyCost;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @d.coder, I followed your advise but now have this error message: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Company' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1"